# unable to search only subsite items using sharepoint search webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, search, search-scope, search-results-webpart

I have a custom page in subsite(SP online site) with Search box and Search result webparts. when i try to search items, it is showing Site collection level items but i need only particular subsite items to display in result webpart.

I have tried using this property; Path:{Site.URL}

By using this without enter anything in search box some results are displaying.

Please help me how can we get search results only when we search any text in search box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked in this syntax:

```
{SearchBoxQuery} Path:{SiteCollection.URL}
```

Answer (score 0):

On that subsite go to **Site Settings**.

Under Search click **Result Sources**.

**Add new Result Source (copy Local SharePoint Results)**.

Set name and under Query Transform open query builder.

Add **Path:{Site.URL}** in Query text after {searchTerms}.

**Save** that new Result Source and **Set as default**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue a few days ago.

Try **Page** -> **Edit Page** ->
at your Search Results Webpart click -> **Edit Web Part**.

In the upshowing WebPartProperties go to **"Change Query".**

In your **query text field** enter: **{ ?{searchboxquery} Path:{Site.URL}}.**

Worked well in my case. Maybe you wil have to change the Path to **Page.URL**.

Have a try.

Hope this works for you.